# Build command in detox

Tags: detox

Looking at this doc: https://github.com/wix/Detox/blob/master/docs/APIRef.Configuration.md

It says that the

> Build command (either xcodebuild, react-native run-ios, etc...), will
> be later available through detox CLI tool.

I'm trying to setup the build command to work with Android. Am I supposed to add `react-native run-android` to the build command? What do they mean by Detox CLI tool?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `build` field is optional, and should contain whichever execution logic needed in order to have the `.apk` file set and ready in the path specified in `binaryPath`. You are more than welcome to refer to the [Detox example project](https://github.com/wix/Detox/blob/master/examples/demo-react-native/detox.config.js#L41), which was set up as a reference exactly for these type of questions.

In any case, from the `react-native` CLI tool's help: `react-native run-android` = `builds your app and starts it on a connected Android emulator or device`. That makes it not very suitable, as we typically want to build the app, and have *detox* launch the emulator (optional) and install the app on the device(s), as needed.